# A proper way to receive applicationContext and avoid re-transfering? - WatchConnectivity

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, applicationcontext, watchconnectivity

I have been working on sending an `int notificationCount` in form of ApplicationsContext from my iOS app to my WatchOS.

`func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {}`

The problem is, the code snippet above only reacts, whenever the notificationCount is changed. Which means when I open my InterfaceController where I need the notificationCount, I don't have any numbers before the value gets updated from the iOS counterpart.

I do suspect that `didReceiveApplicationContext` only when the sending value is not the same. But is there a proper way to check the value of notificationCount for having the same value as the recent transfer to avoid some re-transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Just save the notificationCount in your Extension Delegate's property (or any other instance you might use for storing data) and use it in your controller's awake method (or/and willActivate if appropriate). In addition, you might want to save it in your UserDefaults or a file so it would survive re-launching your app.

Something like this:

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate {
    var notificationCount: Int?

    // ...

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        // do your normal init stuff
        // read notificationCount from UserDefaults
    }

    // ...

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
        if let count = applicationContext["NotificationCount"] {
            notificationCount = count
            // save to UserDefaults here
        }
    }
}
```